# Same fragment in different Tabs in Android

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I have a PagerFragmentAdapter with two tabs but only one fragment PartOne() :

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        switch(arg0){
            case 0:
                PartOne oneFragment = new PartOne();                
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                oneFragment.setArguments(data);
                return oneFragment;
            case 1:
                PartOne twoFragment = new PartOne();
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                twoFragment.setArguments(data);
                return twoFragment; 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When PartOne() loads, I retrieve

```
partChosen = getArguments().getInt("current_page");
```

that I use

```
if (partChosen == 1) { // Code }
```

Used as described, the two instances of the fragment act the same way, giving the same results(as if partChosen == 2 even if it's not). However, when I replace the Fragment PartOne() by PartTwo()* in case 1, they act the way I need them to.

*PartTwo() has the exact same code as PartOne(), just a different name.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is partChosen static?

Comment: Waouuu you found it thanx Benito !

Comment: Could you please explain me why it got stuck? And add an answer that I can validate !

Comment: `static` variables are shared between all instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from repetition, your code is fine.

A better way to write getItem() would be:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    PartOne oneFragment = new PartOne();                
    data.putInt("current_page", position + 1);
    oneFragment.setArguments(data);
    return oneFragment;

}
```

The only problem I can think of is you declared `partChosen` static.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved with:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch(arg0){
            case 0:
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                PartOne oneFragment = new PartOne();                
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                oneFragment.setArguments(data);
                return oneFragment;
            case 1:
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                PartOne twoFragment = new PartOne();
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                twoFragment.setArguments(data);
                return twoFragment; 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and get the args in the onCreateView method of the fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textView.setText(getArguments().getInt("current_page"););

        return view;
    }
```